# 'Connection to the server was unsuccessful' error when launching phonegap app on android emulator

Tags: android, cordova

I am using PhoneGap to build an Android application, the application is a combination of 
phonegap + jquery mobile.

The application successfully launches in the emulator and I was able to debug the application, until yesterday.

Today the application just refuses to launch on the emulator, and I keep getting this error

```
06-25 09:03:24.453: INFO/System.out(305): onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful. URL=file:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to be a phonegap 0.9.3 issue, as other people have reported the same problem (see [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/1363) or [here](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/8ff8cf605bb918db))

The problem might be solved by changing the loadUrlTimeoutValue

```
this.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
```

Comment: but is this only for the emulator i am using phonegap 0.9.5.1 and the app works fine on the device, it only fails in emulator.

Comment: @user160108 I'm not sure it will solve your problem, but other people have reported that this solution fixed it and since the emulator can sometimes be very slow...

Comment: yes the problem is solved, but can I comment out that line when deploying to device or should it be there.

Comment: @user160108 I'm glad it works! You can edit your comments up to 5 minutes after you posted them. But you can always remove it if you'd like (not sure why you want to do that).

Answer (score 1):

Use bigger value then 60sec, emulator can be extremely slow.

**super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 360000);**

and you can refer this also.. 
[Check this!](http://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/01/fix-for-phonegap-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful/)

Comment: Don't you think, that setting this value to 360 seconds, that is five minutes, isn't a little bit madness? I understand, that emulators (and remote debug servers, when doing debug) can become extremely slow. But, don't you think that we can say, that application is useful at all, if it doesn't get reply from server within five minutes? I found default setting (claimed by some, though not cleared in documentation, that it is `2000`) way too slow for old mobile devices and slow emulators. But I think, that timeout of 60 seconds is far, far enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 10000);
```

to the com.mypackage.xxx.java file for 10 sec waiting time.ie,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/home/index.html");
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 10000);
```