# phonegap, connection to server unsuccessful

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to write an Android app with phonegap, and I'm writing a static front page with buttons, which was working until I introduced jQuery mobile and jQuery (which are linked as external files). Now, it gives me this error message (after it produces a blank window for 30 seconds or so):

> Connection to server was unsuccessful to "www/assets/index.html"

Since the message flashes away, I cannot read anymore. Any help?

Comment: I face this error only on virtual device, on real devices this error does not happen.

Answer (score 7):

What exactly do you mean by "linked as external files"?

The jQuery Mobile and jQuery sources either need to be in the assets/www directory or linked to externally on an accessible cdn site with wireless or mobile data enabled.

There's an example [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/included-demo-apps).

Also, see [JQuery Mobile + PhoneGap for Android - Error loading index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544870/jquery-mobile-phonegap-for-android-error-loading-index-html) - Within your custom Activity file before calling super.loadUrl add the following line: super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);

Comment: I could see my page below the error stating my page could not be loaded, and this worked for me.  also detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477798/phonegap-android

Comment: Almost two years later, I'm still at a loss as to how this happened. I had to drop that client - he just couldn't get it to connect on his device! All of the sources were linked and I was using the Phonegap Build service...

Answer (score 4):

Far better solution is to keep a extremely light file as for initial load and then redirect to original index.html. For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>tittle</title>
   <script>
       window.location = './index.html';
   </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't typically a thing you do on the web - why do something like this for Phonegap?

Comment: @DhaivatPandya If nothing worked then this is one of the ways to fix it. If you are not ok with this approach then you need to go back and think what went wrong and why its taking more than 60s or what ever the limit is.

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/home/index.html");
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 10000);
```

I have added 
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 10000);
to com.mypackage.xxx.java file
for 10 second waiting waiting time.

Comment: This did not work for me - the timeout value was not changeable my be (because I was using the Phonegap Build service) - this is honestly something that should be an easy fix for the Phonegap people.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is that you have the `super.loadUrl()` entered incorrectly.
loadUrl should have this string `file:///android_asset/www/index.html` and actually be located in `assets/www/`.

The missing 's' threw me off personally.

### Edit:

Some other things to check:

- The browser is able to access the internet
- Permissions to access the internet.
- Try downloading the jquery, and jqm libraries to the device and storing them with `index.html`. Because the emulator is slow, it may be interfering with the page's response to downloading the libraries. Storing locally should avoid that.

Comment: Are you running in the emulator?

Comment: More specifically, do you have an internet connection within the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

hi i think u load multiple scripts in starting  time so u do some thing like this

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>tittle</title>

        <script>

            window.location='./main.html';

        </script>

    <body>      

    </body>

</html>
```