# Phonegap App Error - connection to the server was unsuccessful

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have the following issue and I'm a bit new to Phonegap! On my index page I have three functions that will create a Javascript Prompt asking the user for their name, email and title (position) and store each to the localStorage. Three items like this:

```
function promptName(){
  var salesPName = prompt("Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen","");
  if(salesPName == null || salesPName == ""){
    promptName()
  }else{
    localStorage.setItem("salesP", salesPName);
  }
}
```

Then using `$(document).ready` I call these three functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(!localStorage.getItem("salesP")){
    promptName();
    promptEmail();
    promptPosition();
  }
});
```

This is all working well, however when deploying to my Android device I get the prompts but before I can complete all three I get an error dialog stating:

> The connection to the server was unsuccessful (file:///android_asset/www/appname/index.html)

Removing the prompts removes the error but I need this functionality. I have tried different ways of calling the functions, for example on the `body` tag's `onload` event or using `.load()`. I still get this error. I thought about setting a Javascript interval to call this after a few seconds (once the page is loaded) as I'm sure the problem is due to Javascript's blocking nature. Has anyone come across this before?

Please note that I added the following to the `com.mypackage.xxx.java` file (as advised from  [phonegap, connection to server unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550889/phonegap-connection-to-server-unsuccessful))

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 10000);
```

And I still get the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with nothing working I put a `setTimeout()`  around my condition like so...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        setTimeout(function (){if(!localStorage.getItem("salesP")){
            // item doesn't exist... so let's raise some dialogs to capture the name, email address and title
            promptName();
            promptEmail();
            promptPosition();
            }
        }, 5000)

});
```

now it works fine... a bit of a fudge but so what, if anyone has any ideas on a better solution or any objections to this please let me know

Comment: https://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/01/fix-for-phonegap-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful/