# connectoin to the server was unsuccessful in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

i am using phonegap,when i tried to load html file get this error

> The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

My code:

```
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

public class LoadHtml extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index5.html");


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_first, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems odd that the error complains about index.html while you are trying to load index5.html. Are you sure this is the right Java class?

Comment: I get this error only on virtual devices. On real devices it does not happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550889/phonegap-connection-to-server-unsuccessful][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550889/phonegap-connection-to-server-unsuccessful

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely due to the speed of the emulator or device, the network is too slow for completing the communication in a default time.

use  **super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);**  before calling   **super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");**

it sets a 60 second timeout for completing the communication.

it works for me.