# Jquery Mobile listview not displaying json data but the browsers are

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile

please check [this url](http://www.qhse-riskapplications.com/m/show_projects.html)(you can view console (on chrome) to see json output.

but when i run this on emulator (uploaded the screenshot), it just shows the search box and no list view.
[image: screenshot]

jquery code:

```
<script>
   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#home', function(){ 

     $.getJSON("http://www.qhse-riskapplications.com/m/show_projec...;, function(projects) {
         $("#projectlist").empty();

         $.each(projects, function(i, projects){
             $("#projectlist").append(generateProjectLink(projects));
              console.log(generateProjectLink(projects));
              //alert(projects.firstName);
         });

         $("#projectlist").listview("refresh");

      });

      function generateProjectLink(projects){
         return '<li><a href="">' + projects.firstName + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + projects.id+'</span></a></li>'
      }
  });
</script>
```

my html has following code

i can make it run on browsers (chrome, safari, FF), but not on emulator or device.

i'm using dreamweaver cs6, php, mysql and phonegap.

Comment: Is the URL from which you are trying to fetch JSON data reachable from the emulator? Could you try reaching that URL from the emulators browser? Maybe you need to allow your emulator to access addresses on the internet.

Comment: An other guess: Are your js libraries properly included? Maybe the discussion here covers your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550889/phonegap-connection-to-server-unsuccessful

Comment: @ErikKinding

the json URL on emulator is working fine and showing the result as desired.

following us the includes in jquery


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>